# Combobox Select de 3 Niveles

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, combobox

Saludos estoy trabajando en un proyecto y requiero hacer un select de 3 niveles hasta el momento he logrado que funcione solo los primeros 2 niveles pero me esta costando hacer funcionar el 3er nivel y no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Aca lo que tengo

Mi codigo en index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showselect(str){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str=="")
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
                }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                 {
                 document.getElementById("municipios").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                 }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","funciones/municipios.php?e="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function showselectP(str){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str=="")
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
                }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                 {
                 document.getElementById("parroquias").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                 }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","funciones/parroquias.php?m="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

    </script>
```

dentro de mi index dentro de codigo php estoy corriendo esto:

```
$modal_editar_usuario .= '
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="estado_usuario">Estado donde Vive</label>
                        <select name="estados" class="form-control" onchange="showselect(this.value)" required >
                            '.
estados().'
                        </select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Estado donde vive.</div>
                    </div>';

                $modal_editar_usuario .= '
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="municipio_usuario">Municipio donde Vive</label>
                        <div id="municipios">
                            <select name="municipios" class="form-control" onchange="showselectP(this.value) required>
                                <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el Municipio donde vive.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';

                    $modal_editar_usuario .= '
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="parroquia_usuario">Parroquia donde Vive</label>
                            <div id="parroquias">
                                <select name="parroquias" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar La Parroquia donde vive.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
```

Estados.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// LISTAR Municipios
function estados(){
    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM estados";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$a = '<option value="">Seleccione</option>';
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            $a .= "<option value='".$fila['id_estado']."'>".$fila['estado']."</option>";
  }
  return $a;


}

?>
```

municipios.php

```
  <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    include('../../funciones/functions.php');

    // LISTAR Municipios
    function municipios(){
        global $db;

    echo '<select name="municipios" class="form-control">';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM municipios";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
      echo '<option value="">Seleccione</option>';
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        if($fila['id_estado'] == $_GET['e']){
                echo "<option value='".$fila['id_municipio']."'>".$fila['municipio']."</option>";;
            }
      }
      echo '</select

>';
}

municipios();

?>
```

Parroquias.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include('../../funciones/functions.php');

// LISTAR Parroquias
function parroquias(){
    global $db;

echo '<select name="parroquias" class="form-control">';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM parroquias";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  echo '<option value="">Seleccione</option>';
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    if($fila['id_municipio'] == $_GET['m']){
            echo "<option value='".$fila['id_parroquia']."'>".$fila['parroquia']."</option>";;
        }
  }
  echo '</select>';
}

parroquias();

?>
```

Asi como tengo mi codigo me permite seleccionar el estado y en el select municipio carga los municipios que corresponden al estado seleccionado, pero no me carga las parroquias que corresponden al municipio seleccionado.

La estructura de la BD es:

**Estado:**

```
id_estado
estado
```

**Municipio:**

```
id_municipio
id_estado
municipio
```

**Parroquia:**

```
id_parroquia
id_municipio
parroquia
```

Comment: ¿Dices que tu código filtra los municipios según el estado seleccionado? No puede ser, o no estás compartiendo el código real, pues no veo ninguna consulta `SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE id_estado=elEstadoSeleccionado`. Debe haber un filtro para que eso ocurra, y lo mismo para las parroquias. Tienes que mostrar la situación actual del código basándote en la realidad. Ese código no filtra los municipios por estado, es imposible.

Comment: @A.Cedano He pensado lo mismo, pero el filtrado lo esta haciendo en el código php `if($fila['id_municipio'] == $_GET['m'])`

Comment: @MikelFerreiro Ok, no me detuve a analizar ese detalle. De todos modos es ilógico traer siempre toooodos los datos para luego filtrar en la lectura. Habría que filtrar en la consulta con un `WHERE`. Dicho esto, a ver si ubicamos el error en tan enrevesado código...

Comment: Tienes 2 `;` en el echo de parraoquia: `echo "<option value='".$fila['id_parroquia']."'>".$fila['parroquia']."</option>";;` puede que sea el fallo, aunque acabo de mirar y también lo tienes en municipio. ¿Te da algún error o algo?, O simplemente no se pinta?

Comment: Te falta la comilla de cierre en `onchange="showselectP(this.value) required>` debe ser `onchange="showselectP(this.value)" required`

Comment: Saludos chicos de pronto no es el mejor de los codigos como dice @A.Cedano este codigo lo estoy tratando de implementar desde  [Aqui](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/2144-select-dependientes-con-ajax/) He aplicado las correcciones de los errores que me lograron identificar pero igual no logro que seleccione en el campo parroquia..!

Comment: No tengo problemas en modificar mi codigo de otra manera que logicamente quede funcional.. aun cuando me imagino que el error debe estar en la asignacion al hacer click, creo que debe existir algun comando que haga el select en un sitio inmediatamente se haga click en otro.. voy a tratar de ver si por alli va la cosa..!

Comment: Primeramente **depura**, pon simplemente `echo "Entró aquí";` en las partes donde tienes dudas. Si el código pasa por ahí, entonces depura  las variables: `while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { var_dump($fila);  /*...resto de tu codigo...*/ }` ya verás si el `var_dump` saca algo o no por pantalla.

Comment: Creo que el error no esta en PHP si no en el mundo oscuro de JavaScript

Comment: Depura también ahí usando `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);` o bien `console.log(xmlhttp);`, Oscuro es todo aquello que no se saca a la luz, depurar precisamente es sinónimo de sacar a la luz, de ver qué hay o qué no hay en lo que estás manejando. En vez de decir *el error no está aquí* ¿no sería mejor que digas: *el error no está ahí, porque depuré haciendo tal cosa y muestra esto y lo otro*.? ¿Probaste lo que te dije en el otro comentario? ¿qué mostró en pantalla?

Comment: Si en el php municipio.php me da resultados pero en el php parroquia.php no es como que el javascript no esta enlazando el php voy a probar con el `console.log` Ah y hoy merezco ser tratado con cariño estoy de cumpleaños jejeje..!!! sigo probando

Comment: Si he verificado y el error debe estar en el script javascript ya que el he hecho `console.log` en ambas function y en la primera function si da resultados `MLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}...........` pero la segunda function no da resultados de hecho he definido una `var qqq = "Prueba";` y no da resultado, como que si no esta funcionando `onchange="showselectP(this.value)`

Comment: Te deseo un feliz cumpleaños... y te sugiero que sigas **depurando**. Para saber si está entrando en ese bloque y si manda datos, pon un alert, por ejemplo: `function showselectP(str){ alert(str); /*resto del codigo*/ }`

Comment: Me di por vencido, he aplicado un nuevo codigo adaptado a lo explicado en: [Este enlace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq04F4hbZmo) me vi en la necedidad de agregar la libreria jquery version 3.1.1 y me esta funcionando aparte de que ahora si comprendo el codigo usado, o por lo menos para mi es mas facil de leer..!